# Google_Drive_API_comments_error

Tags: http, google-drive-api, comments

Good afternoon. I am trying to write a function that will read the comments on a jpg file in google drive. However, when I try to run it it gives me the following error:

An error occurred:

> <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1SbB4VwCIhaS9mdJ_xqcyjenZfxxrpTsY/comments?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}]">

```
def retrieve_comments(service, file_id):
  """Retrieve a list of comments.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to retrieve comments for.
  Returns:
    List of comments.
  """

  try:
    comments = service.comments().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
    return comments.get('items', [])
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
  return None

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', ]
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

service = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
print(retrieve_comments(service, '1SbB4VwCIhaS9mdJ_xqcyjenZfxxrpTsY'))
```

Update: this is what my token.json file looks like:

{"token": "ya29.a0ARrdaM-lbQRcrOHcWXHXVCZ--FHEBFmhetZy5mtKyE-KYg7kkqc7DCB3ELoGWm7DSFFqZ5n7MZ2qtpomhhhh3YjyPlDmFNiBFqW8jfzQcq2bUboJVHWly7w5KajgYBW6vXfpUG7XB-NiSRIGbgGXg7pADS9E", "refresh_token": "1//03RuSdM4_a83LCgYIARAAGAMSNwF-L9Ir99uSssRC7-EDBGOchESXQuY8uQh3BIAUSnUFmT60dipjtvqGslz9wyAl_OnLkoLWdko", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "client_id": "936594993582-hm55manlg9g4hkdeeisq6i4ogqk6are2.apps.googleusercontent.com", "client_secret": "irvWegrf57dztuP6_OigoGIT", "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"], "expiry": "2021-08-19T12:26:14.658525Z"}

This is how my code looks like. any ideas why this might be happening and what I can do to solve it?

Edit: For anyone who runs into the same problem, remember the scopes in the quickstart must be the same as the ones in your python file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Insufficient Permission

Means that the user you are authenticated with does not have permission to do what you are trying to do, or that user has not granted your application permission.

You are trying to use [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/list) this method requires that you have been authorized with one of the following scopes

[image]

Now you appear to be using the following scopes

> 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',

Im not sure why you have drive.file twice, but lets ignore that for now.

As you can see you appear to be using the proper scopes needed by this endpoint.  What i suspect has happened is that you have already authorized the user using a different set of scopes and you then changed the scopes in your application.  When you change the scopes you need to be sure that you have revoked the users access in your application and prompt the user to authorize your application again.  You are probably running on a stored access token and or refresh token which have the old scopes.

The solution will be to simply force your application to authorize your user again, make sure the consent screen popsup.

Comment: I have tried deleting the .json file and running quickstart again. Then, I wrote SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] and tried running it but got the same error. Is that what you meant?